# How to have multiple formulas in 1 cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an If(and) formula as shown below. I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that if E28 is blank then L28 would be left blank as well rather than state pass or fail. Can anyone help?

```
=IF(AND(E28<=$V$9,E28>=$W$9,F28<=$V$10,F28>=$W$10,G28<=$V$11,G28>=$W$11,H28<=$V$12,H28>=$W$12,I28<=$V$13,I28>=$W$13,J28<=$V$14,J28>=$W$14),"Pass","Fail")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data with us, will  help us to test the logic you are trying so far,,,!!

Answer (score 0):

nest your if inside another if:

```
=IF(E28 = "","",IF(AND(E28<=$V$9,E28>=$W$9,F28<=$V$10,F28>=$W$10,G28<=$V$11,G28>=$W$11,H28<=$V$12,H28>=$W$12,I28<=$V$13,I28>=$W$13,J28<=$V$14,J28>=$W$14),"Pass","Fail"))
```